# e-Mail controller - how to implement?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, email

I'm trying to call the e-mail programme from my app. What I have done so far:

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
```

and added delegate:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

then I thought I'd be brave and put this into my code:

```
- (void)sendEmail {


    MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer;

    mailComposer=[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate=self;
    [self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];

    [mailComposer release];

}
```

However, I only get an error message which I do not understand in the slightest. Could anyone please help me to interpret this? It doesn't make any sense to me and doesn't point to a line of code so I don't understand where to start when debugging:

[image]

Comment: did u add framework of messageui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to #import the framework in your .m file

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>
```

Comment: also make sure you have added the framework to the project first.

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't add framework to your project MessageUI framework.

Comment: WELCOME BUDDY.DO CODING SLOW WITH PLANNING.THEN U WONT MISTAKE.ALL THE BEST